# How to auto set value of ordinary column to the value of primary column in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have one table, there are two columns, one is for "serial no" and other is "screening no"
If user is giving screening no. then it will save that screening no.,and if user is not giving screening no. then system will generate the  same value for screening no. as "serial no" value

And for "serial no", I am using @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) annotation 
How could I initialize the same value of "serial no" to "screening no" if user is not giving "screening no".

please help!!
Thankx

Answer (score 0):

In the save/persist method just check for the "screening no" is empty then initialise to the serial no as follows:

```
if(this.screeningNo == null){
this.screeningNo = this.serialNo;
}
```

**(OR)**

Initialize at the attribute declaration level:

```
private int screeningNo = this.serialNo;
```

In this case, if the setter for `screeningNo` is called then the value will get overwritten.

Comment: Hi Arun Thanks for ur reply, I tried both ways but we are getting java.lang.NullPointerException in both cases , I think value for "serialno" is generated at run-time so its getting null as "serialno" value

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace. Cuz we have not done anything which throws NullPointerException.

Comment: Hi Arun Thanks for ur effort, I solved my problem by assigning random number to screeningNo in case user in not giving screeningNo

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing with setter and getters. In the getter method of `screeningNo` you can check for null and set the value from `serialNo`. like

```
public <type> getScreeningNo(){
  if(this.screeningNo == null){
    this.screeningNo = getSerialNo();
  }
}
```

As hibernate will call getter while saving value of that `screeningNo` to DB, by the time the value of `serialNo` will be already set.

Comment: Hi Pokuri, I tried this also still we are getting java.lang.NullPointerException, I also ran application in debug mode then I recognize that hibernate is setting "serialNo" many times means it is calling setter of "serialNo" many times